# Load blank page with empty memory

Tags: memory, google-chrome-devtools

I would like to play around with Google Chrome Memory DevTools panel. The problem is, when I load empty (blank) page it already contains some memory (1.4MB) containing nodes such as:

- (system)
- (array)
- (compiled code)
- (closure)
- Window
- Document
- ...

That causes some noise in my testing. Can I have fully empty site? Is this even possible?

Comment: It's not possible.

Comment: @wOxxOm I see. Do you know where I can get more detailed information about what exactly these things are?

Comment: It's the built-in V8 globals and DOM of any page.